# Precisa instalar composer no servidor?

Tags: php, composer, php-autoload

Estou estudando php e aprendendo a usar o autoload e composer. Consegui um servidor para utilizar durante meus estudos. O servidor deve ter composer instalado para o autoload funcionar?

Comment: Acesse o [link](https://getcomposer.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tecnicamente? Não.

O composer gera um arquivo que fica no diretório 'vendor/autoload.php'. Mas é recomendável instalar o Composer no servidor para executar comandos, atualizações, eventuais instalações de pacotes, etc... Não vejo motivo para não o ter. Abraços.